# PHP Obtener enlace de de página web (web scraping)

Tags: php, web, scraping, enlace

Hola estoy usando un host remoto y quiero obtener este enlace:

https://mrzutv.net/fx27sep.m3u

el cual se encuentra alojado en esta página web: https://mexiqueando.site/m3u-latina-septiembre-2022/, pero este enlace cambia cada ciertos días, excepto esta parte: "https://mrzutv.net/" y esta otra ".m3u"

El resultado sería el siguiente:

https://mrzutv.net/XXXXXXX.m3u

¿Hay alguna manera de hacer redireccionar hacia ese link en específico (terminado en .m3u) en PHP?

Comment: @JiminyCricket. para que sea un duplicado debe estar en el mismo sitio ... no del sitio en ingles... puedes preguntar lo mismo en varios lugares de la red... esperando respuesta desde distintos tipos de sition con puntos de vistas diferentes etc...

Comment: Hola, Bienvenid@ al Sitio, veo que eres nuev@ te recomendaria hacer el [tour] para que conoscas mejor el sitio, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Me parece que a tu POST le falta un Codigo o Ejemplo Minimo Reproducible, Me parece que a tu POST contiene código no formateado, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].